# Connect the 60 pins male CN6 connector of a STM32 Eval board to a wrapping board

Tags: stm32, connector

I need to connect some of the pins on the CN6 connector of a STM32H7 Eval board to my own peripheral.

[image]

I know that this 60 pins male connector is frequently used in the STM32 ecosystem but I have no idea whether it is an electronics standard.

I first tried to directly wrap wires but the pins are too close for my wrapping tools to fit in.

The datasheet mentions that this connector allows to connect "a daughterboard or a standard wrapping board".

I'm a software guy and I didn't find the solution to connect a wrapping board tot this 60 pins connector.

Is it through a ribbon cable ? But is there a wrapping board that connect itself easily with such a ribbon cable ?

Any advice welcome

Comment: This is a 1.27mm by 2.54mm pitch connector. You can get a suitable ribbon cable connector from TE or Molex. This row and column pitch combination is not very common.

Comment: To add to what @LiorBilia said: If all you need is a connector that will mate with it, however, a 3-row connector with a 1.27mm/50mil pin pitch and row spacing would also work. You likely won't get that in a ribbon cable compatible form factor, but if soldering to a PCB is acceptable that would be my first choice (though I haven't looked into it much--there may be disadvantages).

Answer (score 1):

That is the male half of a gendered board-to-board connector.

I used my [connector identification utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=board_to_board_conn) to identify some possible [board-mount mates](https://www.digikey.com/short/2q7982t7), which you can buy from Digikey. Some are surface mounted, some thru-hole. Some are straight, some are right-angle. Pick the one that works best for you.

[image: Hirose HIF6B-60DA-1.27DS(71)]

{[Hirose via Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/hirose-electric-co-ltd/HIF6B-60DA-1-27DS-71/4306413)]

If you prefer a cable-to-board solution, you can use instead a [free-hanging, ribbon-cable mass-terminated, female  connector](https://www.digikey.com/short/3btr90rn), which you can also get from Digikey/

[image: TE 2-111196-2]

{[TE via Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/2-111196-2/807110)}

Comment: Thank you, very interesting. However I don't completely understand. My problem is to be able to connect individual wires to my peripheral (which is on a separated small PCB). That's why I was thinking about using a wrapping board in between. How do I connect a wrapping board to one of the connectors you mentioned ?

Comment: or is it possible to connect wires directly on the connector male pins on the first photo ? Are these pins more distant from one another ?

Comment: Just _some_ circuits? Just a few circuits? If so, just solder wires to them.